# Comprbando si existe usuario Nodejs MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy usando este **route** para verificar que exista el usuario:

```
//comprobar si existe un usuario antes de loggearse
router.get("/checkUser", (req, res, next) => {
  let body = req.body;
  res.send("Cheking user...");
  model.find(
    { email: body.email, password: body.password },
    (err, usuarioEncontrado) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log("USUARIO ENCONTRADO ", usuarioEncontrado);

    }
  );
  console.log(body);
  next();
});
```

Le estoy pasando un usuario que exista pero no me devuelve nada:

```
GET /checkUser?email=pablito%40hotmail.com&password=mipassword 304 3.331 ms - -
USUARIO ENCONTRADO  []
```

---

Ya he encontrado la solucion :

```
router.get("/checkUser", (req, res, next) => {
  let body = req.body;
  let get_email = req.params.email;
  let get_password = req.params.password;

  model.findOne(body,(err, usuarioEncontrado) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log("USUARIO ENCONTRADO ", usuarioEncontrado);

    }
  );

  next();
});
```

**Pero me surgen unas dudas:**

- ¿Por que le tengo que pasar body al a funcion **findOne** si no lo uso?
- ¿Como controlo **si existe o no el usuario** porque he intentado lo que tengo aqui abajo y me da error al poner los **if** para controlar **que hacer dependiendo de i existe o no**?

  //comprobar si existe un usuario antes de loggearse
  router.get("/checkUser", (req, res, next) => {
    let body = req.body;
    let get_email = req.params.email;
    let get_password = req.params.password;

  model.findOne(body,(err, usuarioEncontrado) => {
        if (err) throw err;

  ```
    console.log("USUARIO ENCONTRADO ", usuarioEncontrado);
      if (usuarioEncontrado) {
          res.json({
              'exite':true
          });
      }
      else{
          res.json({
              'existe':false
          })
      }
  }
  ```

  );

  next();
  });

Pero me aparecen las sig

Comment: Hola, estás pasando tus valores en una `query` en la url, pero en el backend los lees en el body. Debes bien cambiar el backend o enviar los parámetros en el body.

Comment: Para que puedas comprobar lo que te dice @MauricioContreras envía un consolé.log con lo que contiene body y veras que el objeto esta vacío.

Comment: Si, asi es . El body esta vacio. Pero no entiendo muy bien a lo que te refieres @MauricioContreras Yo estoy enviando los datos mediante un formulario method="POST" como elijo por donde lo envio ?

Comment: Veo que estás aprendiendo a usar Express y te animo a que continúes. Hay muchos tutoriales por allí que no enseñan de una manera adecuada el uso de esta herramienta. No soy de recomendar tutoriales, en particular porque no hay ninguno que me convenza hasta los momentos. Pero si acostumbro a leer post de [Medium](https://medium.com/search/publications?q=expressjs), casi todos en inglés. Algunos valen la pena. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo Mcuhas gracias, me he visto ya bastantes tutoriales, y siempre que puedo investigo cosas, muchas gracias por mandarme esa pagina web, la investigare a fondo.

Answer (score 2):

Para recibir valores en Express tienes varias alternativas.

**`req.query`**: Esta propiedad contiene un objeto con los valores que se envían en una petición HTTP al servidor mediante una `query` en la url del servicio que queremos consumir. (ver [documentación](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query))

**`req.params`**:  Esta propiedad contiene un objeto con valores mapeados al parámetro de ruta. Por ejemplo: `/users/:id`, en esta ruta, `:id` indica un parámetro. (ver [documentación](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params))

**`req.body`**: Esta propiedad contiene un objeto con la data en formato `key: value`. Por ejemplo: `{"email": "e@mail.com"}`. Comunmente estos valores son enviados mediante el método `POST` y se capturan desde en un formulario que el usuario llena. Para poder usar el contenido de este objeto, se debe `parsear` el `body` de la solicitud, usando un *middleware*, el más común es `body-parser`(ver [documentación](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body))

Por último, si deseas pasar los datos en la `query` tal como lo estás haciendo, debes escribir tu función de la siguiente manera:

```
router.get("/checkUser", (req, res, next) => {
    if(!req.query) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: 'No data received'
        });
    }
    const email = req.query.email;
    const password = req.query.password;
    // res.send("Cheking user..."); <= ESTO NO DEBES HACERLO, YA QUE SOLO SE DEBE ENVIAR UNA RESPUESTA POR PETICION
    model.find({ email: email, password: password }, (err, user) => {
        // if (err) throw err; <= ESTO TAMPOCO, PORQUE DETIENE TU SERVER
        if(err) { // un error indica que hubo problemas con la consulta
            res.status(500).json({
                error: 'Server error'
            });
        }
        if(!user) { // Si el usuario no existe
            res.status(400).json({
                message: 'User not found'
            });
        }
        console.log("USUARIO ENCONTRADO: ", user);
        // AQUI PUEDES LLAMAR A TU SIGUIENTE MIDDLEWARE O DEVOLVER EL RESULTADO
        next(); <= SI VAS A LLAMAR AL SIGUIENTE MIDDLEWARE
        //res.status(200).json(user); // <= SI ENVIAS EL RESULTADO. NO PUEDES HACER AMBAS
    });
});
```

Esta sería un implementación básica de una ruta usando Express y leyendo los parámetros en la `query` de la url.

La url debería tener esta estructura:

```
http://localhost:3000/checkUser?email=pablito@hotmail.com&password=mipassword
```

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que dices que has *enontrado* una solución y tienes otras dudas, entonces te las trataré de aclarar.

- ***¿Porqué le tengo que pasar `body` al a función `findOne` si no lo uso?***: En primer lugar, si no usas `body`, entonces el método `findOne` devolverá un lindo y bello: `[]` (o un error en caso de que la consulta no de pueda realizar). Por lo tanto tal como lo estás haciendo esa función está de adorno.
- ***¿Cómo controlo si existe o no el usuario? porque he intentado lo que tengo aquí abajo y me da error al poner los `if` para controlar qué hacer dependiendo de si existe o no***: Para controlar si el usuario existe debes realizar la consulta a la base de datos. El método `findOne` te devolverá el documento de la colección `users` (si acaso así se llama tu colección) que coincida con el parámetro de búsqueda. En este caso, si hay más de un usuario usando el mismo email devolverá el primero que encuentre. Con esto, ya tienes una forma de verificar. Si te fijas, yo uso un `if(!user)` que claramente indica *si no existe usuario*.

Espero que sea lo que buscabas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, estoy probandolo para que si existe el usuario renderice la pagina de inicio una vez entrado, pero tengo el siguiente problema :

En la vista entra siempre al inicio de la cuenta, pero en log del backend si discrimina cuando existe o no, pero independientemente de lo que diga el backend el frontend envia siempre a la pagina de inicio

Comment: Si implementas lo que respondí, creo que ya no tendrás ese problema que comentas. Fíjate que siempre envío una respuesta al cliente en caso de error o en caso de que no se consiga un usuario, solo se llama a la función `next()` si la búsqueda arroja un usuario encontrado.

Comment: voy a abrir un chat por si pudieras hablar un momento. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91635/consulta-de-nodejs

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario que pases el body para hacer una consula `findOne`, ya que el primer parametro hacer referencia a que recibe `conditions` que es de tipo `object`, ahora bien como la documentación de mongoose nos dice que cuando no se encuentre algo en la consulta, este retornara un valor `null`, entonces hay que validar si nuestro resultado es null.

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
model.findOne({ email: body.email, password: body.password }, (err, usuarioEncontrado) => {
   if (err) throw err;

   if(usuarioEcontrado !== null ) {
     //usuario existe
   } else {
     //usuario no existe
   }
})
```

[Puedes checar la documentación de mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)