# ¿Cómo verificar un username?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo un sistema de registro, pero quiero que el username  y el correo sean únicos. Mi código solo válida si el correo existe.

```
User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
  if (user) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists' });
    res.render('register', {
      errors,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password2
    });
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías colocar el código de tu esquema? Te puedo mostrar cómo crear validaciones a nivel de esquema, para que no tengas que realizar una doble consulta a la base de datos. Saludos

Comment: Relacionado: [**Comprobando si existe usuario Nodejs MongoDB**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/249421/comprbando-si-existe-usuario-nodejs-mongodb)